# Include common tests in Erlang release

Tags: erlang, release, rebar, common-test

I have a project written in Erlang (and releases generated by rebar) and I want to do integration testing in an environment which is as close as possible to the deployment environment.

The project pulls in a few other Erlang applications as dependencies. One of these applications has common tests in test/. It is these tests I wish to run in the release.

Is there maybe a way to have the common tests included in a generated release, and somehow run them on the target instance?

I don't want to run these tests on the application in deps/, but on the actual release itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the tests out of the release. Build the release, then start it from a CT run (test_server has a nice way to start slave nodes). Now you can *call* into the other node to execute test cases.

I find that this method is often easier to get working.